# Datatable to json - c#

Tags: c#, json, datatable, jsonserializer, javascriptserializer

I have a data table like below

| Subject | Question | Qtype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| English | xxxxxxx | Subjective |
| English | yyyyyyy | Subjective |
| English | zzzzzzz | Objective |
| English | sasasas | Objective |
| English | cvcvcvv | Subjective |

Question column will contain the question in text format.

Json should be

```json
{
    "Subject":"English",
    "xxxxxxx":"Subjective",
    "yyyyyyy":"Subjective",
    "zzzzzzz":"Objective",
    "sasasas":"Objective",
    "cvcvcvv":"Subjective"
}
```

I have tried like below. But this will not return above output.

```cs
var list = new List<string[]>();
foreach (DataRow row in dt_questions.Rows)
{
    string Subject   = row["Subject"].ToString();
    string Question= row["Question"].ToString();
    string Qtype= row["Qtype"].ToString();
    list.Add(new string[] { Subject, Question, Qtype});
}
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(list);
```

Comment: If you want named fields, you need to cast the datatable to a list of a class not a list of strings arrays

Comment: JSON is corrected.

Comment: Are the fields Q1...Q5 fixed or might there be some subjects with more or less Q* values? What is the expected output if there is another subject besides "English" in the datatable?

Comment: Subject will always be 'english', But the number of questions, text of question will always be different.

Comment: Can you provide a more extense and diverse dataset, if there is allways the *same* number g Q records related in a group, then can be done chunking the datatable into groups of 5 elements, if not, you need another aproach, and need a goruping element, and if Subject is allways english that can't be done easily

Comment: @DTechy The problem is using the obsolete `JavaScriptSerializer`. That's a legacy class that doesn't even get dates right. It was replaced *10 years ago* by JSON.NET in ASP.NET Web API. JSON.NET was the defacto standard in all .NET projects until System.Text.Json was introduced. It [already handles DataTable](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm) serialization

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Ok  Thankyou for the information, I'm also using Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: So why did you post this code? Post the actual code you used using JSON.NET. Although it looks like your real problem is that you aren't trying to serialize a DataTable as JSON at all. That would mean generating an array, not an object. You're trying to store multiple rows as a single object instead

Comment: What you ask has little to do with DataTable serialization. You're trying to emit a *JSON object* whose property names come from two different columns and values from a third. What happens if the results contain more than one `Subject` value? Would you emit two `Subject` properties? Which one would be the correct one? There's no implied order in a JSON object

Comment: Do you *really* want to produce a dictionary instead of an array? What happens with duplicate `Subject` keys? Wouldn't it make more sense to return one object per `Subject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 'subject' should be used only once, you have to treat this outside the loop, and loop over the rest.
Then use a dictionary instead of a list:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
foreach(string c in "Subject,Question,Qtype".Split(','))
    dt.Columns.Add(c, typeof(string));
    
for(int i = 1; i<= 5;i++)
    dt.Rows.Add("English", $"Q{i}", (i==3 || i==4 ? "Objective" : "Subjective"));   

var dc = new Dictionary<string, string>();

dc.Add("Subject", dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("Subject"));

foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    dc.Add(r.Field<string>("Question"), r.Field<string>("QType"));
}

var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(dc);
```

Or with Newtonsoft:

```
string json2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dc);
```

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` is an obsolete class that was replaced 10 years ago by JSON.NET in ASP.NET Web API. None of this code would be needed if JSON.NET was used

Comment: Sorry the question I have entered is just for a sample. It will be any string. Not from Q1-Q5.

Comment: Which is what I said too.

Comment: @DTechy I just reproduced your sample data. The serialization part does not rely in any way on the question text. Did you try this out?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see what confused me now.